# Bootstrap: match checkbox with dropdown menu

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to match up a checkbox with dropdown menu in my ASP.Net MVC application(the checkbox will enable/disable the dropdown). I tried to alter the [code on the official bootstrap site](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-checkboxes-radios) that shows how to match a checkbox with an input box to fit my own needs. This didn't really work out though.

My html looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        @Html.LabelForConfig(model => model.CompanyPkid)
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsSCompanyForPush)
                            </span>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CompanyPkid, Model.SelectOptions.CompanyPkidList)
                        </div><!-- /input-group -->
                    </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                </div>
```

This give the following result:
[image]

How can I fix this up to make it look cleaner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply the bootstrap input style you need to give the dropdown the `form-control` class:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CompanyPkid, Model.SelectOptions.CompanyPkidList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: thanks that seems to have done the trick. however the checkbox and dropdown are huge. How can I make them smaller?

Comment: @Sperick add the class 'input-group-sm' to the input-group div: <div class="input-group input-group-sm">